# How to remove "To close the window Press ENTER" part in QT console?

Tags: qt, console

Its kind of annoying everytime. I know its like programs way of telling you, that It finished the work.
Is it possible to remove that part or replace it with something else like . or ✔ or somthing else?

Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to change the text that is displayed.

If you're using Qt Creator, you can uncheck the `Projects > Run > Run in terminal` checkbox, so that the application output goes to the Application Output pane and hence won't prompt you to close anything.

You can also remove the `CONFIG += console` line in your project's .pro file. See the [CONFIG](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#config) qmake variable documentation for more information.

Comment: Can you please tell me what CONFIG += console is andd what it does? Also I cant seem to be able to locate .pro file.

Comment: As I said, see the link that I posted for more information. Your .pro file is generally in the same folder as your sources if it's a simple project created with Qt Creator.